# Api key must be initialized (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, api-key, react-on-rails

So, I am currently contributing to open source (React on Rails app).

I am getting the following error when I run: `foreman start -f Procfile.static`

The output on the terminal is:

```
Rajs-MacBook-Pro:Empirical-Core raj$ foreman start -f Procfile.static
17:03:40 rails.1               | started with pid 8018
17:03:40 worker.1              | started with pid 8019
17:03:40 rails-client-assets.1 | started with pid 8020
17:03:40 rails-server-assets.1 | started with pid 8021
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | started with pid 8022
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | started with pid 8023
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | started with pid 8024
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.294 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | 8023:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.294 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | 8024:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.293 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.298 # Redis version=4.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=8022, just started
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | 8023:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.297 # Redis version=4.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=8023, just started
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | 8024:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.295 # Redis version=4.0.8, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=8024, just started
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.298 # Configuration loaded
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | 8023:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.297 # Configuration loaded
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | 8024:C 18 Mar 17:03:40.295 # Configuration loaded
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.300 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | 8023:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.298 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | 8024:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.296 * Increased maximum number of open files to 10032 (it was originally set to 256).
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | 8023:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.355 * Running mode=standalone, port=6378.
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.355 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | 8023:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.355 # Server initialized
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.355 # Server initialized
17:03:40 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.356 * Ready to accept connections
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | 8024:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.356 * Running mode=standalone, port=7654.
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | 8024:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.356 # Server initialized
17:03:40 redis-caching.1       | 8024:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.356 * Ready to accept connections
17:03:40 redis-testing.1       | 8023:M 18 Mar 17:03:40.356 * Ready to accept connections
17:03:40 rails-server-assets.1 | 
17:03:40 rails-server-assets.1 | > @ build:dev:server /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core
17:03:40 rails-server-assets.1 | > (cd client && npm run build:dev:server --silent)
17:03:40 rails-server-assets.1 | 
17:03:40 rails-client-assets.1 | 
17:03:40 rails-client-assets.1 | > @ build:dev:client /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core
17:03:40 rails-client-assets.1 | > (cd client && npm run build:dev:client --silent)
17:03:40 rails-client-assets.1 | 
17:03:41 rails-server-assets.1 | 
17:03:41 rails-server-assets.1 | Webpack is watching the files…
17:03:41 rails-server-assets.1 | 
17:03:42 rails-client-assets.1 | Webpack dev build for Rails
17:03:42 rails-client-assets.1 | 
17:03:42 rails-client-assets.1 | Webpack is watching the files…
17:03:42 rails-client-assets.1 | 
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 | Hash: 4e792d6ddf1ac233e502
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 | Version: webpack 3.11.0
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 | Time: 1283ms
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 |            Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 | server-bundle.js  264 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 |   [89] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 |  [124] multi babel-polyfill 28 bytes {0} [built]
17:03:43 rails-server-assets.1 |     + 325 hidden modules
17:03:44 rails-client-assets.1 | (node:8031) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
17:03:44 rails-client-assets.1 | parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
17:03:51 worker.1              | I, [2018-03-18T17:03:51.894987 #8019]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 2.7.1 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set
17:03:52 worker.1              | W, [2018-03-18T17:03:52.626113 #8019]  WARN -- : [SKYLIGHT] [1.5.0] Running Skylight in development mode. No data will be reported until you deploy your app.
17:03:52 worker.1              | (To disable this message for all local apps, run `skylight disable_dev_warning`.)
17:03:52 rails.1               | W, [2018-03-18T17:03:52.626636 #8018]  WARN -- : [SKYLIGHT] [1.5.0] Running Skylight in development mode. No data will be reported until you deploy your app.
17:03:52 rails.1               | (To disable this message for all local apps, run `skylight disable_dev_warning`.)
17:03:53 rails.1               | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api/client.rb:196:in `check_api_key!': Api key must be initialized (ArgumentError)
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api/client.rb:28:in `initialize'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api.rb:15:in `new'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api.rb:15:in `initialize'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config/initializers/salesmachine.rb:5:in `new'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config/initializers/salesmachine.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/skylight-1.5.0/lib/skylight/probes.rb:81:in `require'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/skylight-1.5.0/lib/skylight/probes.rb:81:in `require'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config.ru:in `new'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config.ru:in `<main>'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/rack-1.6.8/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
17:03:53 rails.1               |    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
17:03:53 worker.1              | Api key must be initialized
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api/client.rb:196:in `check_api_key!'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api/client.rb:28:in `initialize'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api.rb:15:in `new'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/salesmachine-ruby-1.0.0/lib/salesmachine/api.rb:15:in `initialize'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config/initializers/salesmachine.rb:5:in `new'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config/initializers/salesmachine.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/Desktop/Empirical-Core/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/skylight-1.5.0/lib/skylight/probes.rb:81:in `require'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/skylight-1.5.0/lib/skylight/probes.rb:81:in `require'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:254:in `boot_system'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:54:in `run'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/gems/sidekiq-5.0.5/bin/sidekiq:12:in `<top (required)>'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
17:03:53 worker.1              | /Users/raj/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@quill/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
17:03:53 rails.1               | I, [2018-03-18T17:03:51.895036 #8018]  INFO -- sentry: ** [Raven] Raven 2.7.1 configured not to capture errors: DSN not set
17:03:53 rails.1               | => Booting Puma
17:03:53 rails.1               | => Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
17:03:53 rails.1               | => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
17:03:53 rails.1               | => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
17:03:53 rails.1               | Exiting
17:03:53 worker.1              | exited with code 1
17:03:53 system                | sending SIGTERM to all processes
17:03:53 rails.1               | exited with code 1
17:03:53 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:signal-handler (1521372833) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
17:03:53 redis-testing.1       | 8023:signal-handler (1521372833) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
17:03:53 redis-caching.1       | 8024:signal-handler (1521372833) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
17:03:53 redis-caching.1       | 8024:M 18 Mar 17:03:53.469 # User requested shutdown...
17:03:53 redis-testing.1       | 8023:M 18 Mar 17:03:53.469 # User requested shutdown...
17:03:53 redis-caching.1       | 8024:M 18 Mar 17:03:53.469 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
17:03:53 redis-testing.1       | 8023:M 18 Mar 17:03:53.469 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
17:03:53 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:M 18 Mar 17:03:53.489 # User requested shutdown...
17:03:53 redis-sidekiq.1       | 8022:M 18 Mar 17:03:53.489 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
17:03:53 redis-caching.1       | exited with code 0
17:03:53 redis-testing.1       | exited with code 0
17:03:53 redis-sidekiq.1       | exited with code 0
17:03:53 rails-server-assets.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
17:03:53 rails-client-assets.1 | terminated by SIGTERM
```

Please help!

Comment: Error message pretty explicit. You need to generate api key for `salesmachine` gem

Comment: I have never worked with Ruby before. How do I do that?

Comment: Its not about ruby. Its about this particular gem

Comment: https://docs.salesmachine.io/#install check out note about token there

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how I can generate the api key for the salesmachine gem?

Comment: Ive never worked with salesmachine before. Dont even know what this is. Go through their docs or google it. You got this buddy

Comment: You can register on https://www.salesmachine.io/ and I will get token along the way or you can ask for that in repo you want contribute to. Also you can just comment out that gem in `Gemfile` if its optional.

Comment: What project you want to contribute to? Because that part about token should be documented somewhere

Comment: I tried to comment it out in the Gemfile but it didn't work.
I am contributing to Quill (https://github.com/empirical-org/Empirical-Core). It has a config file set for this which is probably working with Environment Variables.

Comment: Open an issue and ask core devs about that. Also this is a good idea to mention that token in [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/empirical-org/Empirical-Core/blob/develop/CONTRIBUTING.md) and [.env-sample](https://github.com/empirical-org/Empirical-Core/blob/develop/.env-sample) as your first contribution

Comment: In general open source projects setup should be as easy as possible and any caveats like that one should be mentioned in build or contributing guide

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Martin!
I figured out a work-around by commenting some unnecessary code. It works. :)